# How to switch quickly between video and AP photo mode of Canon 600D?

Tags: canon, video, canon-600d, aperture-priority

I have recently got a 600D which is a great camera, but there is one thing I find very annoying. When I am shooting video and suddenly want to capture a still image in AP mode, it takes 3+ seconds to turn the wheel from a video to AP mode to make a shot.

Are there any shortcuts available so I can do it in one button click and avoid turning that wheel thing?

Comment: This may be a pro-grade feature, I can't be sure as I have not used a 600D...but have you simply tried to take a photo while your recording? With my 7D, while recording video, I can simply press the shutter button, and it will snap a photo right then and there. It takes about a second at most (depends what mirror silence mode you have on), and automatically returns to recording afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

As jrista mentioned and I've confirmed, you are able to capture an image while a video is recording though it seems to skip recording for about a second while it shoots. You may also want to turn on the 'autofocus with shutter button during recording' in the menu but the noise can be quite loud in the recording. It's not possible to capture in Av mode like this though; the image will take on settings of the video recording.